# WUBI install not completing on Dell Latitude D600 using 10.04 and 10.10

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, installation, wubi

While trying to install a dual boot from LiveCD, WUBI seems to go through all the steps correctly. It unpacks everything, reboots, starts to finalize the install, brings up the install slide show and seems to do everything necessary. The slide show disappears and what is left is what would normally be the background, however there is no login, no panels, no response to any input or keystrokes. Using 10.04 I had a mouse cursor (working) with 10.10, not even that. In 10.04 The only way to reboot is to shutdown using the power switch. When it reboots it goes through the "finalizing install" phase again. In 10.10 if I hit the power switch it brings up a shutdown menu that doesn't respond to the keyboard, but does shutdown when the 60 seconds expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was all related to what turned out to be a bad hard disk that showed up in another problem [Gparted can't create ext3 or ext4 partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23233/gparted-cant-create-ext3-or-ext4-partitions)